# Java Graphics Program Does Not Close as Expected

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a kind of simplified graphics library on top of the built-in Java graphics system.  I want to use it in teaching so students can create graphical programs without needing to create their own classes, or especially need to use inheritance.

Anyway, as I have it, the windows do not close as I expect them to and I cannot figure out why.  The weird thing is that if I have a println in the main program loop it *does* work.  What's going on?  Here is a minimal example:

```
package test;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.LinkedList;

/** enumeration of the different types of events which a window can produce */
enum EventType {
    Closed,
    KeyPressed,
    KeyReleased,
    MousePressed,
    MouseReleased,
    MouseMoved
}

/** a class which represents an event which a window can produce */
class Event {
    private EventType t;

    /** create a new event of a given type */
    public Event(EventType type) {
        t = type;
    }

    /** check which type of event it is */
    public EventType getType( ) {
        return t;
    }
}

/** a graphics window */
class Window implements WindowListener {
    private JFrame frame;
    private boolean open;
    private Queue<Event> events;

    /** create the window */
    public Window(String title, int width, int height, boolean resizable) {
        frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setResizable(resizable);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.addWindowListener(this);
        events = new LinkedList<>( );
        open = true;
    }

    /** checks whether the window is still open or not */
    public boolean isOpen( ) {
        return open;
    }

    /** closes the window */
    public void close( ) {
        open = false;
        frame.dispose( );
    }

    /** returns the next event, or null if there is none */
    public Event pollEvent( ) {
        return events.poll( );
    }

    /* functions which implement window listening */
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) { }
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) { }
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) { }
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) { }
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) { }
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) { }
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Adding close event");
        events.add(new Event(EventType.Closed));
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // create the window
        Window window = new Window("Hello world!", 800, 600, false);

        // while the window is open
        while (window.isOpen( )) {
            // check for events
            Event event = window.pollEvent( );
            if (event != null) {
                switch (event.getType( )) {
                    // handle the window close event
                    case Closed:
                        System.out.println("Calling close");
                        window.close( );
                        break;
                }
            }

            // when this line is un-commented, it works as expected???
            //System.out.print('.');
        }
        System.out.println("All done!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but why do you have whitespaces between brackets `window.close( )`?

Comment: @LuxxMiner, I want to explicitly catch the closing which is why I implement implements WindowListener.  According to the docs (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) that should be an OK approach?

Comment: @MuratK.probably a code formatter setting... You can define the same in Eclipse for example...

Comment: Can you tell what you want to achive? I've launched this program and after closing it, I have "Adding close event Calling close
All done!"

Comment: @MuratK. that is just my style.  I know it's unusual, but they look weird to me as ().  I should probably learn to do that though...

Comment: Tip: try not to name your classes with the same names as classes from relevant packages. `Window` and `Event` are already used in the graphical contexts you are using.

Comment: @IanFinlayson You can also catch the closing event with `EXIT_ON_CLOSE` or `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` as the default close operation, it will still work.

Comment: @Mati maybe it is platform-specific, but when I run this program (on Linux), the window does not close, but just stays open forever.

Comment: @LuxxMiner Oh interesting!  I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.  The issue was a lack of synchronization between the Java event threads and my main thread.  My main thread was constantly calling which pulls an event from the event Queue.

Then the Java event thread would at some point add the close event to the queue.  This was not synchronized, so the event was somehow lost.  I'm guessing that it was called "during" a check of the queue and was not committed.

Adding the "synchronized" keyword to "windowClosing" which enqueues events, and "pollEvent" fixed the issue.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are calling `dispose()` from the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).  This should work for you:

```
   switch (event.getType()) {
    // handle the window close event
        case Closed:
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("Calling close");
                    window.close();
                }
            });

            break;
    }
```

Comment: @JamesWierzba it's called from his window.close() method.

Comment: Thanks so much.  This wasn't exactly what I needed, but talking about the EDT which I hadn't heard of led me to the answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/34136793/2213804).  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

`frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);`

to

`frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);`

Comment: That doesn't really help.  It *does* cause the window to close, but the program still hangs forever and never finishes main.

Comment: Remove the while loop, it looks like it might be an infinite loop. Setting `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` should stop the VM entirely when the windows close.

Comment: That makes sense, but that's not how I want it to work.  I want to put a procedural style API on top of the callback based one.  So that you could write graphical programs just in a main function.